# Failed to send request to Salesforce url

Tags: soap-api, webservices, java

I am working on Java ( JSP & Servlet )

I am creating JAVA Dynamic Web project to Create SalesForce Data Loader...

I am using SOAP API as Web Service...

I am using sales force "Partner WSDL" API

for Creating data Loader...

so some time I am trying to Import data into salesforce org using my data loader. 
I am using `Try...catch` blocks in many places for Error Handling and display `e.getMessage()` to user.

But sometimes I hit an Internet issue and it gives me the error:

```
> Failed to send Request : http://na10.salesforce.com/sopa/[15 digit salesforce id of my organization]"
```

Once this error happens it keeps happening until i restart my tomcat server.

Comment: How reliable is your internet connection? It seems like you are having intermittent networking issues. Also, can you include the actual URL as it appears in the error message? Feel free to change your Org ID. `/sopa/` doesn't seem at all correct. Did you change that for the question?

Comment: This sounds more like a local issue than anything to do with the platform.

Comment: @MattLacey I have been facing this same issue for this URL  `https://nylic--DEV201.cs44.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/40.0/00D7A000000D7vo` This doesn't always happen. It is intermittent please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The user needs to put in the login server name (cs16.salesforce.com) from the setting menu of dataloader. Then the user needs to get his token from the main salesforce login. To reach the token, he needs to go to Setup, go to My Personal Information, then Reset My Security Token. He will receive the token in an email. He must that token after he types in his password, no spaces.